# List of lists of objects to JSON with Python

Tags: python, json, list, object, serialization

I have a List with multi lists of objects:

```
ob = Obj()
for p in l:
    list_url_commune = scrapingCities(base_url, p)
    for u in list_url_commune:
        list_name = scaping_creches(base_url, u, number_page)
        list_dep.append(list_name)

 json_string = json.dumps([ob.__dict__ for ob in list_dep])
 print json_string
```

**list_dep** is the list with all the lists with Objects

Then, I would like to convert all the Objects in only **one JSON**.

In my case, I have an error with `json.dumps([ob.__dict__ for ob in list_dep])`

(notice: it works fine if I have only one list but here it is a List of lists)

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '__dict__'
```

Thanks for your help !

Pedro

Comment: You should try the second solution from the question you asked an hour ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like you noticed yourself, it works fine with a list of objects, but not with a list of lists of objects.
You need to go deeper:

```
json.dumps([[ob.__dict__ for ob in lst] for lst in list_dep])
```